# Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando criar esse projeto https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn539646.aspx 
mas após abrir o projeto pela primeira vez e compilar, ocorre o erro:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou
>   uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly
>   localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Espero que isso o ajude: [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267006/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc)

Comment: Você iniciou o projeto como empty ou com o template do MVC?

Comment: Funcionou, Caio. Obrigada.